# DateTime.Now missing 1 hour daylight savings

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

Hi all
Basically I have a piece of code that reads the DateTime.Now values into a struct. Passes the struct to a DLL to be stored, updated, etc.

I noticed only recently that when I sync my DLL with the DateTime.now values, the hour value is always 1 hour behind??? e.g. PC time = 17.20,,,, DLL Time = 16.20???

Also this code has always worked before the daylight savings occured, like always! I havnt changed anything in it, and I notice don my laptop when I select the clock, it mentions about the daylight saving hour.

Does anyone know why this is happening? please?

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check the culture of the thread that your code runs.
It is not necessary the current culture of your system.

Set a breakpoint and check the value of:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
```

Check also the TimeZone class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thank you v much I really appreciate your help, DLL now displaying correct time :D now its wine shopping time :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Have a nice celebration! :)